# Getting a specific part of e.parameter

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest

I have a Google App Script that writes form data to a spreadsheet upon submission on my site.

I have many different forms, and I'd like to write their data to the same Spreadsheet, but to different 'Sheets' (i.e tabs @ bottom "form1, form2, form3") within.

Each form has a hidden input that names it. I think that by isolating the input name, I can write an `if statement` that pushes the form data to the right sheet.

example of HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-type" value="form1">
*Name: <input type="text" name="john">

<input type="hidden" name="form-type" value="form2">
*Name: <input type="text" name="peter">
```

Javascript on website - handling the data for POST'ing to Google App Script:

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {  // handles form submit withtout any jquery
    event.preventDefault();           // we are submitting via xhr below
    var data = getFormData();         // get the values submitted in the form

    var url = event.target.action;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

   // url encode form data for sending as post data
   var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
       return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]);
       }).join('&');
       console.log("ENCODED IS: " + encoded);
xhr.send(encoded);
 }
}
```

The encoded data looks like this:

```
ENCODED IS: form-type=form1&name=john  
                 OR 
ENCODED IS: form-type=form2&name=paul
```

The Google App Script function responsible for populating the spreadsheet is:

```
try {
    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName('form1'); // here is where to define which sheet a response should be added to
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row     = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp
// loop through the header columns
for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
  if(headers[i].length > 0) {
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data to row
  }
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
catch(error) {
   Logger.log(e);
}
finally {
   return;
}
```

How do I access the specific `e.parameter`(`form-type`) that I need in order to be able to discern which form was used and route it accordingly?

For more info you can reference (https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server")

Comment: why wouldn't you look at it to see how it is built ? use `Logger.log(JSON.Stringify(e))`

Comment: AFAIK the log only works for when the script is run in-browser, not the site it's being executed on thus being entirely unhelpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doGet parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#doGetParams) documentation:

*The second parameter is called `parameter`, and it is an Object containing each parameter and value pair*

So, something like:

```
var type = e.parameter['form-type'];
```

Should work?

Comment: thanks - i tried variations of this unfruitfully, the only difference is that I didn't store into a variable, maybe that was the issue? IN any case this worked - thanks again!